# Awk function to parse binary data (like binary command in Tcl)?

Tags: parsing, awk, tcl

Is there a way to get the same effect in (g)awk as the binary command in Tcl?

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/binary.htm

Something so I can do `binary(result_array, input_str, format_str)`, returning length of R array.

```
c = binary(R, 'abcdef', '@0a4@4a2')
```

This would parse `'abcdef'` so that `R[1]='abcd'`, `R[2]='ef'`, `c=2` (unless I got my untested syntax wrong)

I am most interested in scanning input, but also in formatting output.

I am very open to alternative approaches as well.

Comment: @Etan Thanks for the reformatting...

Comment: There's nothing built-in that works quite like that that I'm aware of but you can slice and dice input any way you like with the built in string functions... though I don't know how well awk handles binary data (specifically `NUL`).

Comment: What is it you actually want to do overall and what do your input and output data look like?

Comment: I don't have a particular example.  I sometimes want to use the fixed width gawk facility but it is pretty awkward, at least for me.  I am also about to teach a data cleaning class, and it would be nice to have this example.